# How to close application in x seconds if users doesn't respond using c#

Tags: c#

I want to close console application if user doesn't respond in lets say 5 min in the start. I am using c#

Comment: Use a timer which starts counting on app Load. On user response stop timer

Comment: And next, with `Timer` or `CancellationTokenSource`, use `Close()` on the main form or `Application.Exit()` or `Environment.Exit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start timer set values
var timer = new Timer(timenew, null, 60000,0 )
if you don't need timer anymore timer.Dispose()
write end code in timenew method

Answer (score 1):

you can use CancellationTokenSource with delay parameter inside `static async Task main`

```
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(1000 * 60 * 5);

    await Task.Run(() => myFnc, source.Token)
```